# "Un-Pivot" from chart to rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a chart that looks like this:

[image: SO19459731 first example]

and I need to return the value from the appropriate cell into this:

[image: SO19459731 second example]

For example, the first value under "Number of Records" would be 131.

Sorry for the lack of info, I'm not sure of the terminology here.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetPivotData function. See
http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html.
In your case, you will need to combine lo and hi into a single string for measure1 and measure2.
By default, if you reference a cell belonging to a PivotTable, the appropriate GetPivotData formula will be generated for you. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287736.
You can the modify the formula by passing the proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my unpivot add-in, available [here](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/), and then

- run a find / replace to turn the " to " into a space
- run text to columns to split your measure 1 and measure 2 columns into lo and hi columns.